# Guzzle concurrent requests - which is the requested url from the response

Tags: php, concurrency, guzzle

I have used the guzzle library to make some concurrent requests. The code to accomplish this:

```
public function concurrentRequests(array $uri)
{
    $client = $this;
    $requests = function ($total) use ($client, $uri) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
            yield function () use ($client, $uri, $i) {
                return $client->requestAsync('GET', $uri[$i]);
            };
        }
    };

    $pool = Pool::batch($client, $requests(count($uri)), [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
            // this is delivered each successful response
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            // this is delivered each failed request
        },
    ]);

    return $pool;
}
```

I want to know which request belongs to each response. Is there any way to do it while iterate over the responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, because method **Pool::batch**

> Returns an array containing the response or an exception in the same order that the requests were sent.